# Blank rows when exported to Excel from Crystal Report with Sub Report

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, subreport

we have a Crystal report with Suv-report. When we tried exporting it to Excel, it creates a blank row above and below each row with data that comes from the sub-report.  how to resolve this?
Main Report

[image]

Sub Report - TranDetails

[image]

I've tried the below:

1. Suppressing empty sections
2. Suppress blank sub-report
3. Resizing the fiels
4. Aligning fields.

Is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/2353) by Ken Hamady, "The only method I found that worked was to use the regular Excel Export instead of “Data Only”.  But you have to line up the subreport  (as well as the objects within the subreport) so that they are in line with the main report objects.  Line them up carefully and they will export to excel with subreport objects aligned correctly."

As an alternative, at least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) automatically removes blank rows from Excel exports.